# Dynamic LINQ and Kendo MVC wrappers

Tags: entity-framework, kendo-asp.net-mvc, dynamic-linq

I'm using `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` and `EntityFramework` library to generate a query like this:

```
var q = context.Items.Select("new(SomeProperty)")
```

The `q` is of type `IQueryable` at the moment. I can successfully apply `OrderBy`, `Take`, `Skip` and then execute the query.

But if I try to use the extension method from Kendo, things go south:

```
var results = q.ToDataSourceResult(new DataSourceRequest())
```

I get an Exception:

> NotSupportedException
>
> Unknown LINQ expression of type 'Dynamic'.

I know that the `ToDataSourceResult` method adds the `OrderBy`, `Take` and `Skip` to the `IQueryable` to do the paging so that's the most likely source of the problem (it does create a dynamic expression if the object is `object` or `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`)

Any idea how to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this package https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx which is created for Kendo Grid queries and uses `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`

Comment: https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx uses GPL license hence only suitable for Open source projects which is counter intuitive as Kendo components are licensed per developer hence only used in closed source projects.